# Handling Nodejs streams with AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, sockets, stream

I am using nodejs streams to fetch data from my level database (using leveldb). Here is a snippet of the code I use:

```
  app.get('/my/route', function (req, res, next) {

    leveldb.createValueStream(options)
    .pipe(map.obj(function (hash) {
        level.get(somekeys, function (err, item) {

          return item
        })
      }))
    .pipe(res)
  })
```

So far, I have been using the `list-stream` module to get the data on the client side.

Now I'd like to retrieve the information on the client side as a stream. I've read this post (http://www.kdelemme.com/2014/04/24/use-socket-io-to-stream-tweets-between-nodejs-and-angularjs/) on how to do it using socket.io but I don't want to use socket.io

Is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: I'd throw the stream directly to the response from the server, not passing it over angularjs

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [Shoe](https://github.com/substack/shoe). You have to compile the client code with browserify and you can have a stream in the browser that receives the data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

The `createValueStream` basically is a read stream, then you can listen to the event eg., `data`, `end`: https://github.com/substack/node-levelup#createValueStream

Just need to listen to `end` event to finish the stream.

```
  app.get('/my/route', function (req, res, next) {

    leveldb.createValueStream(options)
    .pipe(map.obj(function (hash) {
        level.get(somekeys, function (err, item) {
          return item
        })
      }))
    .pipe(res)
    .on('end', res.end)
  })
```