# How to read a nodejs stream in angular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

In nodejs I send a stream to clients like this:

```
DockerService.get().pull('my/image', function(err, stream) {
  if (err) {
    return res.badRequest(err);
  } else {
    return stream.pipe(res);
  }
});
```

This is triggered from a angularjs client using **$http.get**:

```
pull: function() {
  var url = ENV.apiEndpoint + '/docker/pull';
  var promise = $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
    return response;
  }).error(function(data, status) {

  });
  return promise;
}
```

However I cannot read the stream. From angular I get an error message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Object.parse (native)
    at fromJson (file://build/vendor/angular/angular.js:1065:14)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (file://build/vendor/angular/angular.js:8579:16)
    at file://build/vendor/angular/angular.js:8664:12
    at forEach (file://build/vendor/angular/angular.js:323:20)
    at transformData (file://build/vendor/angular/angular.js:8663:3)
    at transformResponse (file://build/vendor/angular/angular.js:9389:23)
    at processQueue (file://build/vendor/angular/angular.js:13189:27)
    at file://build/vendor/angular/angular.js:13205:27
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (file://build/vendor/angular/angular.js:14401:28)
```

I cannot find any information on how to handle streams in angular. Can you help me out?

**Headers:**

[image]

The response is too large to present it here, so here is the first part of it:

[image]

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the HTTP headers and body that your server code is returning? My guess is you have mismatched 'Content-Type' header for application/json but a plain text message body from `badRequest(err)`.

Comment: @PeterLyons The get request itself returns 200 OK. In network tab of chrome I can see the piped response. However in angular the error callback is triggered. The response is of type JSON. badRequest is not called at all.

Comment: see here if it works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300350/handling-nodejs-streams-with-angularjs

Comment: (really) Can you show the HTTP headers and body that your server code is running? That's how I/we might be able to help you. Put code snippets in your question with the raw HTTP data, not an English description thereof. Then we can troubleshoot. It's clear the response body is not valid json, so we need to troubleshoot if this is chunked encoding issue or what.

Comment: @PeterLyons ok, I updated my question with headers and response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So that's not valid JSON, it's a series of newline-delimited (presumably) JSON messages. That's what the "unexpected token '{'" means. Angular's built-in parser doesn't support that out of the box. The question isn't really about streaming vs. buffered data, it's just a body format angularjs doesn't directly support. You'll need to ensure angular's built-in parser is bypassed and then you can split the string on newline and try/catch parsing each line as a JSON object.

FYI to my knowledge the best module for streaming into the browser is [oboe.js](http://oboejs.com/). You may be able to use [RonB/angular-oboe](https://github.com/RonB/angular-oboe) coupled with some code to buffer each line then parse the ndjson syntax into a stream of JS objects.

Answer (score 1):

try to add:

```
res.attachment()
```

or

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': data.ContentType });
```

*maybe problem is there...*

in your code it will looks like this:

```
DockerService.get().pull('my/image', function(err, stream) {
  if (err) {
    return res.badRequest(err);
  } else {
    res.attachment('your_file.jpg'); // add file name here like req.files.name
    return stream.pipe(res);
  }
});
```

or

```
DockerService.get().pull('my/image', function(err, stream) {
  if (err) {
    return res.badRequest(err);
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': data.ContentType }); //switch data.ContentType to yours or get it from the file
    return stream.pipe(res);
  }
});
```

sometimes use res.attachment is good idea, cos it uses right headers